# Updating html element by partial called from javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, partial

I have a container `td` element that I populate successfuly with other elements using an HTML partial, it's done when the page loads.

The partial runs over a *task* object that it gets as a param and desides which elements to add.

After a specific action is done the *task* object is updated and I want to update the container by running the partial again.

I'm calling this partial from my `create.js.haml` with the updated *task*, the partial runs and builds the correct updated HTML (I can see it in the Firebug response).

But the actual page **doesn't** update. What am I missing here?

Here are my files:

`html.haml` that holds the container `td`:

```
%td#task-categories{ :class => "#{dom_id(task)}_categories"}
  = render 'task_categories_mini_bar', :task => task
```

The partial `html.haml`:

```
- _MAX_DISPLAYED_CAT = 3
- cat_index = 0
- task.categories.each do |category|
  - if (cat_index == _MAX_DISPLAYED_CAT)
    %td{:style => "padding-left:1px; padding-right:5px"} ...
    - break
  - cat_index += 1
  %td{ :class => "task-category-color_#{dom_id(category)}",
  :style => "width:60px; background:#{category.color}; border:solid 1pt lightblue; border-radius:3pt; text-align:center; "}
    = truncate(category.name, :length => 10)
```

Combined together they build this HTML:

```
<td id="task-categories" class="task_3_categories"> </td>
<td class="task-category-color_category_1" style="width:60px; background:#b8d7ff; border:solid 1pt lightblue; border-radius:3pt; text-align:center; "> cat1 </td>
<td class="task-category-color_category_2" style="width:60px; background:#ff8fcb; border:solid 1pt lightblue; border-radius:3pt; text-align:center; "> cat2 </td>
```

There's another problem here - the two added category tds are added below the first container td. How can I add them to it and not after it?

Now here is the `create.js.haml` that calls the partial again:

```
$('td.#{dom_id(@task)}_categories').html(#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'tasks/task_categories_mini_bar', :locals => {:task => @task}))})
```

Again the response HTML does displays a new HTML but the page doesn't update.

I'm using rails 3.0.10 Thanks allot, Eyal.

Comment: Is somebody out there? I still need some help here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK then, what I was missing was " " around the call for the partial in my ajax create.js.haml

```
$('td.#{dom_id(@task)}_categories').html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'tasks/task_categories_mini_bar', :locals => {:task => @task}))}")
```

Thats all.